# firebase "long link is not parsable"

Tags: javascript, rest, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to shorten a longLink with firebase and the REST API but I get the following response and I don't know what is wrong:

Response:

```
   {
        "error": {
            "code": 400,
            "message": "Long link is not parsable: https://www.google.de [https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#create_a_short_link_from_parameters]",
            "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
        }
    }
```

And this is how I do it:

The Request: https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=(*hereismyapikey*)

the Body lookes like this:

```
{
   "longDynamicLink": "https://www.google.de",
   "suffix": {
    "option": "SHORT"
  }
}
```

I tried first with the real URL I want to shorten. Same error. Than with google and with and without the http(s). I'm out of options and hope somebody sees what I did wrong here.

**EDIT:** Full Postman request:

```
    "item": [
            {
                "name": "shortLinks",
                "request": {
                    "method": "POST",
                    "header": [
                        {
                            "key": "Content-Type",
                            "value": "application/json"
                        }
                    ],
                    "body": {
                        "mode": "raw",
                        "raw": "{\r\n   \"longDynamicLink\": \"www.google.de\",\r\n   \"suffix\": {\r\n    \"option\": \"SHORT\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
                    },
                    "url": {
                        "raw": "https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=xxx",
                        "protocol": "https",
                        "host": [
                            "firebasedynamiclinks",
                            "googleapis",
                            "com"
                        ],
                        "path": [
                            "v1",
                            "shortLinks"
                        ],
                        "query": [
                            {
                                "key": "key",
                                "value": "xxx"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "response": []
        }
    ]
```

Comment: show you complete request i.e. the curl request or postman request. Hide your api key

Comment: @UmarHussain II added it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the simple method for creating dynamic link which is roughly equals to the manual creation of dynamic link : https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually

In the docs if you see the link passed in example carefully you will see the pattern as below:

```
https://your_subdomain.page.link/?link=your_deep_link&apn=package_name[&amv=minimum_version][&afl=fallback_link]
```

So you should format the input link according to this or create using the parameters which has very good breakdown of parameters in json:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#create_a_short_link_from_parameters

Here is the api reference for firebase dynamic link creation from parameters:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener#parameters

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to add the Firebase Dynamic Links domain in front of my domain...

Answer (score 4):

I find the JSON parameter method is easier.

```
var body = {
  "dynamicLinkInfo": {
    "dynamicLinkDomain": "yourcustom.page.link",
    "link": fileUrl
  },
  "suffix": {
    "option": "SHORT"
  }
};
```

Then if you're using Node. The [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) package REST call would work like:

```
  var fetchFileUrl = fetch(YOUR_SHORTLINK_URL, { 
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  }).then(function(response){
    return response.json();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the url used by your Firebase dynamic link in the longDynamicLink parameter.
If your dynamic link uses the `https://myshorter.test` url the longDynamicLink becomes
`https://myshorter.test?link=` followed by your url.

For example

```
{
   "longDynamicLink": "https://myshorter.test/?link=https://stackoverflow.com/",
   "suffix": {
     "option": "SHORT"
   }
}
```